# Sum of convex functions

Tags: calculus, convex-optimization

Let $f: R \rightarrow R$ be a convex function. Define the function $g$ to be the sum of $f(x)$ taking on different values, i.e. $g(1,2)=f(1)+f(2)$. Does $g$ possess any interesting/special properties other than the fact that it is also convex? Suggestions or references are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is really not clear what you are asking.

Comment: The way you write it, $g$ appears to be a constant, not a function.

Comment: In your post $g$ does not seem to be a function, but rather a series (so, if convergent, which is not clear, just one value).  So saying "the fact that it is also convex" seems out of place here.

Comment: Apart from the difficulty with $g$ can you please tell me what unrealized means? I searched google "unrealized convex function" and none of the results contains unrealized.

Comment: Let's say we have another convex function $r$, and define $h(1,1)=f(1)+r(1)$. And let's specify $g(1,1)=f(1)+f(1)$, does $g$ possess some interesting property that $h$ does not have since it sums over the same function?

Comment: My intuition suggests that the answer is no, that the arbitrary nature of $f$ makes treating $h$ and $g$ equivalently valid. But that's just my two cents

Comment: I assume you are investigating the function $g(x,y) = f(x) + f(y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be many interesting properties, depending on what you are looking for. Here are some examples:

1. The problem $\min_{x_1, \dots, x_n} g(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ is separable. Can be minimized w.r.t $x$ and $y$ separately.
2. The Hessian matrix of $g$, if $f$ are all twice differentiable, is diagonal. It might help if you are minimizing $g(x) + h(x)$, where the Hessian of $h$ has low rank, and you are using Newton's method. Another example where it might help is when you are minimizing $g(x)$ subject to $A x + b$, and $A$ has low rank.
3. Using separability, it is also easy, in many cases, to derive a dual. For example, look at minimizing $g(x)$ subject to $\|x\|_2 \leq 1$.

If you tell us what exactly you are looking for, we might be able to find more `interesting' properties.